# Showing that statistic is unbiased

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $X $ be observed data. Let $\hat{\theta}(X)$ be an unbiased
estimate of $\theta$ and let T be a sucient statistic for $\theta$. Define the new estimator 
$\hat\theta^{*}$ of $\theta$,

$$ \hat\theta^{*}(X) =E(\hat\theta(X)| T)
$$

Then, show that:

$ \hat\theta^{*}(X)$ is unbiased

Comment: Use that in general: $E[E[X\mid Y]]=E[X]$ whatever $X$ and $Y$ may be (such that the conditional expectation exists).

Comment: related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204890/showing-that-statistic-is-unbiased

Comment: and to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204888/improving-estimators